# Subclasses of UIButton loaded from nibs are not initialized properly

Tags: iphone, nib

I have a very simple subclass of UIButton:

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@end

@implementation MyButton

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]))
        return nil;

    NSLog(@"-[%@ initWithCoder:%@]", self, decoder);

    return self;
}

@end
```

In Interface Builder I add a UIButton, set its button type to *Rounded Rect* and its class identity to `MyButton`.

When running, I have the following log:

```
-[<MyButton: 0x5b23970; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (103 242; 114 37); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5b23a90>> initWithCoder:<UINibDecoder: 0x6819200>]
```

but the button is not a round rect button anymore.

Observed on both iOS 3.2 and iOS 4.

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

*Create an instance of MyButton programmatically* is not an acceptable answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmatically, you instantiate a button with `+[UIButton buttonWithType:]` which is actually a factory that returns a subclass of UIButton. So if you derive from UIButton you actually don't derive from your round rect button class (`UIRoundedRectButton`) but from a generic button class. But you are not allowed to subclass from `UIRoundedRectButton` AFAIK since it's an internal class.

It seems to be problematic to derive from UIButton, I've seen a lot of people recommed to derive from UIControl instead and implement the drawing yourself.

But you might find these articles helpful:

[How to override -drawrect in UIButton subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816024/how-to-override-drawrect-in-uibutton-subclass)

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/284622-how-to-subclass-uibutton.html

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Also, I don't know why you want to derive from UIButton, but if you want to do some customization that does not involve overwriting any other methods it might be helpful to use the fact that you can do something like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
   // Decode the frame
   CGRect decodedFrame = ...;
   [self release];
   self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   [self setFrame:decodedFrame];
   // Do the custom setup to the button
   return self;
}
```

Comment: The code above seems promising but I can't make it work. I thought I could use it to perform customization on an IBOutlet UIButton, but alas. I'd be interested to know how the two people who upvoted this answer implemented it.

Comment: I'm having trouble deducing what we're supposed to do to decode the frame. Any hints?

Comment: @jemmons: You could use `NSStringFromCGRect` and `CGRectFromString`.

Comment: @DarkDust Thank you! Though that's not the part that's mysterious. Where do I get the string that I `CGRectFromString` my rect from? `decoder` doesn't have any keys for "frame", "rect", "bounds", or even "size" or "center". So what exactly did you do to decode the frame?

Comment: Either you encode and decode them all yourself or you try calling `[super initWithCoder:]` and `[super encodeWithCoder:]`. If you still have problems, please ask a new question instead of discussing this in comments.

Comment: I down vote this because original poster has no idea how to obtain decodedFrame yet still posts this as answer. This is rather confusing than useful.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is acceptable for your needs, but I tend to prefer to override `-awakeFromNib` instead of `-initWithCoder:` in these circumstances. Does doing this resolve the issue you’re seeing?

Comment: +1 I don't understand why you got downvoted here, it's a valid answer.