# Using a UIButton subclass on the storyboard makes the button's border vanish

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, uistoryboard

I want to create a very simple subclass of UIButton to add some extra functionality, but it seems that when I use it on the storyboard, my button's border disappears.

After some testing, it seems that using *any* custom UIButton subclass has this effect, even with a totally empty interface and implementation.

It's easily reproducible. Try the following steps:

1) Create a new single view application
2) Add a UIButton to the middle of the view in the storyboard
3) Run in the simulator.

You should see a UIButton with a border, as expected. Now...

4) Create a UIButton subclass called SomeUIButtonClass with an empty interface declaration and an empty implementation, like so:

SomeUIButtonSubclass.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SomeUIButtonSubclass : UIButton

@end
```

SomeUIButtonSubclass.m:

```
#import "SomeUIButtonSubclass.h"

@implementation SomeUIButtonSubclass

@end
```

5) On the storyboard, select the button you added earlier, and in the Identity Inspector, under Custom Class, set the Class to `SomeUIButtonSubclass`.
6) Run in the simulator again.

You will see a button with no border.

I'm getting used to iOS development being crazy, but this is even more deranged than usual.

Why does this happen, and what do I need to do to prevent it?

Comment: Well you need to tell the button what type of button to be...

Comment: you have to set properties of button in SomeUIButtonSubclass like border,borderwidth etc.

Comment: @Unicorn Why? Are there things that need to be set explicitly for subclasses of UIButton that have defaults only when using the base class? If so, what are those things (and where are they documented)? I don't see any reason why the button's existing attributes, properties or behaviour should change as a result of it being a (empty) subclass of UIButton - am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638053/subclasses-of-uibutton-loaded-from-nibs-are-not-initialized-properly

Comment: @Desdenova Awesome, thank you. That's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this, as discussed in [Subclasses of UIButton loaded from nibs are not initialized properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638053/subclasses-of-uibutton-loaded-from-nibs-are-not-initialized-properly), is that the 'types' for a `UIButton` that you can select from the storyboard are actually implemented as `UIButton` subclasses. `UIButton`s have no border by default; the border comes from the 'System' or 'Rounded Rect' type.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType:) for the code-based equivalent of selecting a type in interface builder hint at this, and at the fact that these 'types' are thus incompatible with custom subclasses:

> #### buttonWithType:
>
> ...
>
> This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects with specific configurations. If you subclass `UIButton`, this method does not return an instance of your subclass.

When setting both a 'type' and a custom class in Interface Builder, iOS will ignore the type completely in favour of your explicitly specified subclass.