# Create custom buttons for Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4, button, interface-builder

Does anyone know how to create custom buttons for Interface Builder? Like instead of have just a regular Round Rect Button, I want to have like a custom 3D button and some random image background for that button. How to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you're asking about how to do this with Interface Builder *per se*, or do you just want to know how to do this with xCode? You can create custom buttons quite easily if you skip IB altogether.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Exactly right. You just wouldn't be able to see the effect (or configure anything beyond the standard button's configurables) in IB without an IB palette plug-in.

Comment: sorry boys, maybe I'm asking the wrong way, let me make this question simpler, how do I create a custom button in Photoshop and import it to Interface Builder?

Comment: That's a totally different question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will either need to find a third-party class (ideally with an Interface Builder plug-in so you can see it live in the IB file) or subclass UIButton or NSButton/NSButtonCell for Mac and provide your own 3D rainbow unicorn drawing behavior. :-)

Interface Builder can only show you classes it knows about - you can't add behavior / modify existing drawing behavior there because that's the wrong tool for the job. You'll need to find someone else's or subclass your own in code *then* let IB know about it.

**Update based on OP's comment**

You can use `-setImage:forState:` to supply your custom image for the given states.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in Interface Builder is prohibitively complicated (writing an Interface Builder plugin is a non-trivial task). However, you can subclass UIControl (which is just a UIView) and define your custom drawing in the subclass.

Then, in Interface Builder, change the class of the object you've subclassesed to your new class, and everything should work correctly.

Relevant reading:

- [How to override -drawrect in UIButton subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816024/how-to-override-drawrect-in-uibutton-subclass)
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/284622-how-to-subclass-uibutton.html (If you really need to subclass UIButton instead)

Comment: *"To do it in Interface Builder is likely complicated."* No, it's flat-out impossible. IB only lets you use existing classes and, if there's an IBPalette plugin for the control, it lets you customize the existing behavior in IB's inspector. To teach a class a new trick requires subclassing in code. To teach IB about providing UI for its new tricks requires an IB palette plug-in.

Comment: That's why thats not the answer I gave. The answer is "subclass UIControl, here are some resources".

Comment: I implied that he wouldn't want to do it that way and provided an alternative. It is not impossible - it *is* a complete pain and should be avoided at all costs. [edit] It is, of course, impossible in Xcode 4, but that wasn't part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to use an image as the background for the button. For example you can use this tool to easily generate buttons with gradients, http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/uibutton-builder/id408204223?mt=8

If you want anything more fancy it's probably time to start Photoshop ;-)