# UIButton Subclass - Setting Properties?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, uibutton

I've created a Subclass of UIButton to give it a white 2px No Radii border, and now I'm trying to "globally" set it's font, font color, and background color depending on the button state.

The font does not set. Nor do the colors or the background colors. What's going on? Here's my code. I hope you can help :)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    
    [[self titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ZegoeUI" size:18]];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if(self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

             [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[self.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
[self.layer setCornerRadius:0.0];
[self.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
}
```

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong. I have this class, and have linked Buttons in IB, and set the class type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have created the custom subclass buttons in IB, `initWithFrame:` will not be called. You need to override `initWithCoder:`, or, preferably, create a separate setup method that is called both from `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`.

For the first case:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
if (self) {

    [[self titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ZegoeUI" size:18]];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if(self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: How exactly would I go about that exactly? I've never been to University, it's all self-taught so far..

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it (without IB):

```
+ (instancetype)customButtonWithCustomArgument:(id)customValue {
    XYZCustomButtom *customButton = [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    customButton.customProperty = customValue;
    [customButton customFunctionality];
    return customButton;
}
```

Works also with other types, `UIButtonTypeSystem` is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton is a class cluster. You really shouldn't be subclassing as the classes it represents are private.

Comment: It's not technically a class cluster but you do have a good point, it can get complicated when subclassing (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816024/how-to-override-drawrect-in-uibutton-subclass), and subclassing UIControl may be a better bet.