# Issues with putting a UIButton in a subclassed UIView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can I put a `UIButton` in a subclassed `UIView` to create graphics for the `UIButton`, or is this a problem?  What is best approach then?

Comment: I think you should detail more what do you really want to do. UIAppearance is a new API that can fit in some cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put a UIButton in a subclass of UIView. There are many reasons to do that.

But if your goal is to change what the button's appearance, then you should create a subclass of `UIButton` and override `drawRect:`.

Comment: Just fyi, subclassing UIButton doesn't work very well. Here's an SO post about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816024/how-to-override-drawrect-in-uibutton-subclass