# UIButton with different color text in each line

Tags: uibutton

I want to have a UIButton with two lines of text, with each line in different color. Is it possible to have like that ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Approaches I can think of :

**Approach 1 (easy)** : Make it as an image button

**Approach 2 (hard)** : Make a custom UIButton, with 2 separate UILabel, such that you can configure different colors for them

To achieve Approach 2, you first create a class with UIButton as superclass. Then, override `- (void)drawRect` method. In order not to repeat answer in SO, please read this: [How to override -drawrect in UIButton subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816024/how-to-override-drawrect-in-uibutton-subclass)

Comment: Thanks for the approaches. 
Solution 1: It is not possible in my case,since i need to internationalize the text and it will be overhead by keeping different image for each language.
Solution 2: Can u suggest me with some code for this.? Looks handy for my project

Comment: Localizing images are common in apps. You don't need to over-worry of this approach. ( will post 2nd approach in answer )

Answer (score 1):

Hi this answer only applicable in above ios 6...

Use ios 6 's attributed text to achieve this...

```
NSString* infoString=@"This is an example of Attributed String";

    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:infoString];
    NSInteger _stringLength=[infoString length];

    UIColor *_red=[UIColor redColor];
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0f];
    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_red range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength/2)];
    [self.attribButton setAttributedTitle:attString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.attribButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;
```

Try like this...

Answer (score 1):

```
In Swift

var main_string = "Hello World"
var string_to_color = "World"
var range = (main_string as NSString).rangeOfString(string_to_color)
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:main_string)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: appSingleton.appRedColor , range: range)
self.celciusButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes sure..!!! make an image what you exactly want to show then set the image as an background of that button..! its simple...

Answer (score 0):

1. First, make your button of "custom" type. If you need to do that programmatically:

   UIButton* myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];

   myButton.frame = CGRectMake (x,y,width,height);
2. Now make your labels:

   UILabel* line1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,buttonWidth,buttonHeight/2)];

   UILabel* line2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,buttonHeight/2,buttonWidth,buttonHeight/2)];
3. And assign the text colors you want:

   line1.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

   line2.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
4. Then add the labels to the button, and the button to your view:

   [myButton addSubview:line1];

   [myButton addSubview:line2];

   [self.view addSubview:myButton]; // only if you've created the button programmatically